# Spring Security Authentication at bean/controller is never called

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

I am new in Spring, currently learning Spring Web Security for login and encountered several problems. I am using Spring Security 5, JSF 2.2, and Primefaces 6.1.
 
First of all, my Authentication method at `LoginBean` was never called. It will go through the method `loadUserByUsername()` until return the `UserDetails` object, but my method in bean will never been called. My another curious is where the `UserDetails` object will return to in `loadUserByUsername()` method? Below is my implementation:
**LoginBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean extends BaseBean
{
    @Autowired
    private transient AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String login()
    {
        try
        {
            Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
            Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
            if (result.isAuthenticated())
            {
                Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(result.getAuthorities());
                if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN"))
                    return SystemUtils.getSavedUrl("admin");
                else if (roles.contains("ROLE_USER"))
                    return SystemUtils.getSavedUrl("user");
            }
        } catch (BadCredentialsException badCredentialsException)
        {
            FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(
                    "Login Failed: please check your username/password and try again.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
        } catch (LockedException lockedException)
        {
            FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage("Account Locked: please contact your administrator.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
        } catch (DisabledException disabledException)
        {
            FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage("Account Disabled: please contact your administrator.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userService;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
    {
        web.debug(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('USER')");
        // login
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login.xhtml").permitAll()
                .successHandler(getAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(getAuthenticationFailureHandler());
        // logout
        http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/index.xhtml").invalidateHttpSession(true);
        // require all requests to be authenticated except for the resources
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**", "/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        // not needed as JSF 2.2 is implicitly protected against CSRF
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403.xhtml");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.authenticationProvider(getAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler getAuthenticationFailureHandler()
    {
        return new CustomeAuthFailureHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler getAuthenticationSuccessHandler()
    {
        return new CustomAuthSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider getAuthenticationProvider() throws Exception
    {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
    {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**AccountServiceImpl.java** (Class which implements `UserDetailsService`)

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
{
    System.out.println("username is:-" + username);
    //My account model is implement UserDetails interface
    AccountModel user = repository.findByUsername(username);
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user: " + username);
    }
    if (user.getRole().isEmpty())
    {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User" + username + "has no authorities");
    }
    System.out.println("Password is:-" + user.getPassword().toString());
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getRole());
    user.setAuthorities(new HashSet<>(authorities));

    return user;
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<RoleModel> userRoles)
{
    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    // Build user's authorities
    for (RoleModel userRole : userRoles)
    {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole()));
    }
    List<GrantedAuthority> result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);
    return result;
}
```

**login.xhtml**

```
<h:form prependId="false">
    <p:messages showDetail="true" closable="true" autoUpdate="true"
        globalOnly="true" />
    <p:panelGrid>
        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel for="username" value="Username: " />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:inputText id="username" value="#{loginBean.username}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:row>

        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel for="password" value="Password: " />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:password id="password" value="#{loginBean.password}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
            <p:column colspan="2">
                <p:commandButton value="Login" process="@form" ajax="false"
                    actionListener="#{loginBean.login}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

With the implementation above, login will never be successful, although the username and password was provided correctly according to the data in database. Is there any wrong with my implemenation or config? And another problem is although `UsernameNotFoundException` is thrown in `loadUserByUsername`, the exception message still not showing in console (but other exception message will show, only this exception won't), is it normal?

**** **UPDATE** ****
I have tried to follow [this site](http://fmanea.blogspot.my/2015/04/jsf-login-through-spring-security-400.html).

> Be sure that:
>
> - you have not overriden the default mapping for login-processing-url    (default value "/login" as oposed to "/j_spring_security_check" for
>     older versions of Spring
> - have the ids of user and password input buttons as "username" and    "password" respectively (be aware older Spring versions have the
>     defaults set to "j_xxx"; you can actually configure these values from 
>     username-parameter and password-parameter attributes of login
>     element)
> - use ajax="false" in button definition
> - add prependId="false" to form definition
> - have the FORWARD and REQUEST dispatcher parameters set as shown above

As mentioned in the first point, I remove `loginPage("/login.xhtml")`, but it works **ONLY** when you login through the URL `localhost:8080/Project/login.xhtml` which point to your custome login page. It doesn't work if you access through the spring default login page which is `localhost:8080/Project/login`.
The problem is `login.xhtml` isn't the default login page, so in some cases like if user is accessing a page which required credential, it will redirect user to default login page `/login` instead of my login page `/login.xhtml`.

I have also tried to set it as `loginPage("/login")`, but if you access the URL like `localhost:8080/Project/login (without the extension .xhtml)`, it will return 404.

Comment: As far as I remember you should set the `label` or `id` attribute of `p:inputText` and `p:password` to `j_username` and `j_password` exact values.

Comment: You should give it a try to change your fields like this: `<p:inputText  id="j_username" label="j_username" value="#{loginBean.username}" />` and `<p:password id="j_password" label="j_password" value="#{loginBean.password}" />`

Comment: Another tip for LoginBean's `public String login()` method not being called is because you set the `actionListener="#{loginBean.login}"` and actionListener method should have `javax.faces.ActionEvent e` as the argument in it's signature. So either change the `login()` method signature into `login(ActionEvent e)` or change the `actionListener="#{loginBean.login}"` into `action="#{loginBean.login}"`

Comment: Narrow down the problem. Does removing the panelgrid make it work? Does changing  `p:commandButton` to `h:commandButton` make it work? (99% certain it does not) Does using static username/password make it work (99% certain it does not)? Then you have less code and make it easier for others to help. Hence the requests to make an [mcve] as mentioned in [ask]

Comment: Thanks for your all help. I have added `.usernameParameter("username")` and `.passwordParameter("password")` to solve the `id` problem and add `()` into `actionListener` which mentioned by @STaefi. My login mechanism works now, but the code at login method inside `LoginBean` still not triggered, `CustomeAuthFailureHandler` and `CustomeAuthSuccessHandler` will be executed. Is it normal?

Comment: did you try to change `actionListener` into `action`? use `action="#{loginBean.login}` instead of `actionListener="#{loginBean.login}"`

Comment: @STaefi Yes I did, still not working. May I ask what will be the flow of the whole process? which will be executed 1st and which is next? By right, the successHandler will be executed 1st or method in controller/bean? and also controller will be executed first or `loadUserByUsername`?